# Detect if an R session is run in RStudio at startup

Tags: r, session, rstudio

I use R both in the terminal and in RStudio (on mac and linux) and wonder if it is possible to use different `.Rprofile`s for the two, or preferably use the same base `.Rprofile` but source different environment specific tweak scripts.

I thought it would work to place the following code in my `.Rprofile`, but unfortunately `session_info` isn't set at the time `.First` is run. Neither is `Sys.getenv`.

```
.First <- function(){
    # [STUFF I ALWAYS WANT TO DO]
    # Load my favourite packages
    # Set CRAN mirror
    # etc. etc.

    # [ENVIRONMENT SPECIFIC TWEAKS]
    if(grepl("RStudio", session_info()$platform$ui)){
        tryCatch(source("~/.R_RStudio"), error=print)
    } else {
        tryCatch(source("~/.R_terminal"), error=print)
    }
}
```

I also tried setting `alias R='R --args terminal'` in `.bash_profile` which does allow me to detect if the session was started from bash, but it screws up `R CMD ...` and any script that uses other command line arguments.

I realise it might not be possible to detect from within an R session where it was started from, but perhaps there is some clever option in RStudio I am not aware of.

Comment: You could do something like `if (!is.na(Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO", unset = NA)) { ... }`; RStudio will always set the `RSTUDIO` environment variable upon launch.

Comment: @KevinUshey Thank you so much! It works brilliantly. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it right away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can detect whether RStudio is hosting the R session by checking for the value of the `RSTUDIO` environment variable. For example,

```
if (!is.na(Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO", unset = NA))) {
    # RStudio specific code
}
```